# Expando vs regular Model with blank properties

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a situation in which a Model that I use has a number of properties needed for all entities and a few that are specific to one of two alternatives, like in the following example:

```py
class Machine(ndb.Model):

    #Properties for all machines:
    price = ndb.FloatProperty()
    model = ndb.StringProperty()
    vendor = ndb.KeyProperty()
    #...

    #Properties exclusive to type A machines:
    foo1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    foo2 = ndb.StringProperty()

    #Properties exclusive to type B machines:
    bar1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    bar2 = ndb.StringProperty()
```

From what I understand, I could take one of two paths. Either I make it a regular ndb.Model and just leave some properties without content or I could use an ndb.Expando Model and set the fixed properties in advance and just add the others depending on the case.

As I understand it, the Expando Model is useful when you don't know the properties that you will need, but I do know in advance all the properties needed (foo1, foo2, bar1, bar2). Should I use Expando or is it alright to use a regular ndb.Model and leave a few properties blank for each entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario I would seriously consider using ndb.PolyModel

```
class Machine(ndb.Model):

    #Properties for all machines:
    price = ndb.FloatProperty()
    model = ndb.StringProperty()
    vendor = ndb.KeyProperty()

class MachineA(Machine):
    foo1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    foo2 = ndb.StringProperty()

class MachineB(Machine):
    bar1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    bar2 = ndb.StringProperty()
```

This then allows you to query for all Machine's,

by Machine.query()  or individual Machine types with MachineB.query()

Just my 2c.  (I have a number of projects using this.  For instance, a Product and different Product types that have different additional properties), e.g a Plant vs a Pump, both being basic Products, with price, categorisation, photos, etc) but a plant will have different classifications (flowering, non-flowering) and a pump will have flow rate, watts, etc)  But I can find all all products less < $25 (plant or otherwise) by `Product.query(Product.price < 25)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can I also do this if Machine is a StructuredProperty? I also have a case in which this happens, exactly like this just that instead of Machine being a full-fledged entity, it's a StructuredProperty (a property within a bigger entity). Can I still do what you suggest here in that case?

Comment: Whilst the end result might be similar the approaches are different and each has it strengths and weaknesses.  There some restrictions around nesting repeated properties, and queries for items with structured properties that are nested don't work the way you might like in a number of scenarios.

Comment: In my case they don't have much data and it is only relevant for the entity, and from what I've tested it's enough for querying purposes. What I meant is having something like this example: class "Things" which has a structured property Machine which has two types: MachineA and MachineB. Is this possible or should I avoid it?